# Combining different tables and extracting data on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am going through some kind of problem. Here is the table schema.
I have two tables job,application.

```
Application: aid,aname,stime,jname
Job:jid,jname,aid,start,end

Application table:    
aid  aname   stime  
A    ABC     23-SEP-13  
B    DEF     24-SEP-13

Job table:  
jid  jname  aid      start                 end  
1    job1   A   10-OCT-13 13:06:20  11-OCT-13 13:06:45  
2    job2   A   10-OCT-13 14:06:20  11-OCT-13 14:09:55  
3    job1   B   10-OCT-13 15:16:20  11-OCT-13 15:06:45  
4    job2   B   10-OCT-13 15:26:20  11-OCT-13 15:46:45
```

I need the output as follows. 
I need to generate the differences between the start and end times of all the jobs in every application.

```
aname   stime     jname   (end-start)Days  Hours  Minutes  Seconds
 ABC   23-SEP-13   job1        1            0       0       25
 ABC   23-SEP-13   job2        1            0       3       35
 DEF   24-SEP-13   job1        1            0       10      25
 DEF   24-SEP-13   job2        1            0       20      25
```

I tried using in clause to extract but here the problem is I am unable to retrieve multiple columns from the second table.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
   SELECT a.aname, 
          A.stime, 
          j.jname, 
          floor(end - start) DAYS ,
          MOD(FLOOR ((end - start) * 24), 24) HOURS ,
          MOD (FLOOR ((end - start) * 24 * 60), 60) MINUTES ,
          MOD (FLOOR ((end - start) * 24 * 60 * 60), 60) SECS
   FROM   application a,
          JOB j
   WHERE  j.aid = a.aid;
```

With your sample data.

```
WITH application(aid, aname, stime) AS
(
SELECT  'A', 'ABC', TO_DATE('23-SEP-13', 'DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'DEF', TO_DATE('24-SEP-13', 'DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL
),
JOB(JID, JNAME, AID, START_, END_) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'job1', 'A', TO_DATE('10-OCT-13 13:06:20', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11-OCT-13 13:06:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'job2', 'A', TO_DATE('10-OCT-13 14:06:20', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11-OCT-13 14:09:55', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'job1', 'B', TO_DATE('10-OCT-13 15:16:20', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11-OCT-13 15:06:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'job2', 'B', TO_DATE('10-OCT-13 15:26:20', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11-OCT-13 15:46:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT a.aname, 
     A.stime, 
     j.jname, 
     floor(end_ - start_) DAYS ,
     MOD(FLOOR ((end_ - start_) * 24), 24) HOURS ,
     MOD (FLOOR ((end_ - start_) * 24 * 60), 60) MINUTES ,
     MOD (FLOOR ((end_ - start_) * 24 * 60 * 60), 60) SECS
FROM   application a,
     JOB j
WHERE  j.aid = a.aid
AND    a.stime > to_date('23-sep-12','dd-mon-yy');
```

Comment: Hi,If i am applying filter option on a.stime it is retreiving wrong results.Please check once.

Comment: Please let me know the filter condition you applied.

Comment: What is the datatype of field `stime`?

Comment: Date is the datatype of stime

Comment: Ok, then you need to filter it like, 
`a.stime > to_date('30-sep-13','dd-mon-yy')`

Comment: Do we need to specify not null condition anywhere because some rows are showing no data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38529/discussion-between-dba-and-user2037445)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  using [**TIMESTAMPDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) specify the format like want to get difference in months ,days,minutes or seconds

```
SELECT a.aname ,a.stime ,  j.jname,  
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,j.`end`,j.`start`) AS 'end-start',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,j.`end`,j.`start`) AS `hours`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,j.`end`,j.`start`) AS `minutes`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,j.`end`,j.`start`) AS `seconds`
FROM `Application` a
LEFT JOIN `Job` j ON (j.aid =a.aid)
```

> NOTE for mysql ,make sure you have used correct data types for the date columns

Comment: Not sure what you are trying  to say *Not the converted value* ?

Comment: Yes. It will extract the total days, total hours, total minutes and seconds. You have to subtract the number of days to the number of hours up and the number of hours and days to the minutes and so on...

Comment: So that if you add all of the minutes, hours, days and seconds it would be exactly equal to the time difference

Answer (score 0):

As I see I reckon your schema is not properly normalized.

I would suggest the following design instead:

```
Application (aid, aname, stime, jid)
Job (jid, jname, start, end)
```

The application table would contain applications for jobs. We must consider that one application is made for one single job and any job can have 0, 1 or more applications at any given time.
Hence I have added a foreign key `jid` to the `Application` table that references `Job.jid`.

You can query like this to get the data you desire:

```
SELECT a.aname, a.stime, j.jname,
       INTERVAL (j.end - j.start) DAY TO SECOND AS end_start
  FROM job j INNER JOIN application a
       ON a.jid = j.jid
```

Note that this query is applicable only on Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,but the database is already designed and I had no part in it. Actually the application may contain multiple jobs rather than the one you specified.